# Nodejs application hangs after page refresh

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

What would be the cause for having a request done and after refreshing page(aka making a new request) page hang(is loading forever) ? How can I debug this thing ?

My code looks something like:

```
if(params are not good){
    res.status(500).json("Invalid date.");
}else{
    doDatabaseQuery(callback);
    callback.onSuccess(data) => res.status(200).json(data);
    callback.onError(err) => res.status(500).json(err);
}
```

If I change code and instead of `res.status(200).json(data)` I have `return res.status(200)...` I get: `Can\'t set headers after they are sent.` after more than 1 request.

EDIT:

The problem seems to be that `doDatabaseQuery()`. This method just call .find({}) on a mongoose model. Does the async request isn't killed when I press the refresh button ?

Comment: to debug nodeJS app you can use node-inspector {https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector}

Comment: I'm using that. But I don't know where I'm supposed to put the breakpoints.

Comment: you put the breakpoints in chrome where you see the source code for NodeJS app.

Comment: I mean: `What lines should I inspect ?` How can I know where my app hangs ?

Comment: if you are not sure, you can put the breakpoint on the first line of your request method and step line by line by pressing. F11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed `doDatabaseQuery()`. For other users that read this: what you need to be aware is that nodejs application really `kill the async`(and I said that in a positive way) but this can be tricky. So watch your callbacks and if you are not sure where application hangs use `node-inspector`.